# Image Dithering: How would I calculate quantization error and nearest colour to implement in a Floyd-Steinburg algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, graphics

I intend to display (4, 8 or 16 bit per channel - no alpha) images on a 1 bit display in an embedded system.  Images are stored in RGB tuples.  My intention is to use Floyd-Steinburg, as it looks reasonably good, is more than quick enough and concise in code.

In reference to the WikiPedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering), I have two questions.

**What would the best practice for expressing nearest colour be?**  Would the following work? (ignore that I'm returning a structure in c)

```
typedef rgb16_tag { unsigned short r, g, b } rgb16;

rgb16 nearest_1bit_colour(rgb16 p) {
    double c; rgb16 r;
    c  = ((double)(p.r + p.g + p.b + 3 * (1 << 15))) / ( 3.0 * (1 << 16));
    if (c>= 1.0) { 
       r.r = r.g = r.b = 1;
    } else {
       r.r = r.g = r.b = 0;
    }
    return r;
 }
```

and, **Is the expression of  quantization error done on a per channel basis?**  i.e. does this make sense?

```
rgb16 q, new, old, image[X][Y];
int x, y;

... /* (somewhere in the nested loops) */
    old = image[x][y];
    new = nearest_1bit_colour(old);

    /* Repeat the following for each colour channel seperately. */
    q.{r,g,b} = old.{r,g,b} - new.{r,g,b};

    image[x+1][y].{r,g,b}   = image[x+1][y].{r,g,b} + 7/16 *   q.{r,g,b}
    image[x-1][y+1].{r,g,b} = image[x-1][y+1].{r,g,b} + 3/16 * q.{r,g,b}
    image[x][y+1].{r,g,b}   = image[x][y+1].{r,g,b} + 5/16 *   q.{r,g,b}
    image[x+1][y+1].{r,g,b} = image[x+1][y+1].{r,g,b} + 1/16 * q.{r,g,b}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen two typical approaches to measuring the difference between two colors.  The most common way is probably to just find the Euclidian distance between them through the color cube:

```
float r = i.r - j.r;
float g = i.g - j.g;
float b = i.b - j.b;
float diff = sqrtf( r * r + g + g + b * b );
```

The other is just to average the absolute differences, possibly weighting for luminance:

```
float diff = 0.30f * fabs( i.r - j.r ) +
             0.59f * fabs( i.g - j.g ) +
             0.11f * fabs( i.b - j.b );
```

As to your second question, yes.  Accumulate the error separately in each channel.

**Edit**: Misread at first and missed that this was for a bi-level display.  In that case, I'd suggest just using luminance:

```
float luminance = 0.30f * p.r + 0.59f * p.g + 0.11f * p.b;
if ( luminance > 0.5f * channelMax ) {
     // white
} else {
     // black
}
```

Comment: A good answer, but I'd add that you want to find out if the color is closer to black or to white, so using black as the first color and comparing to `0.5*diff(black,white)` is the right way to use those formulas for this.

Comment: @schnaader -- Hm, you're right.  I misread that this was for a bi-level application.

Comment: Are the values for `p` in `float luminance = 0.30f * p.r + 0.59f * p.g + 0.11f * p.b;` normalized?  If not, I can assure you the following inequality is a near certainty.

Comment: @Jamie  - Gah!  You're quite right.  (I've been working with normalized floating point colors all day.)  The 0.5 in the following conditional there should be one half of whatever the maximum value in a channel can be.

Comment: I get the gist of it ... could you take a peek at my answer and see if I understood your luminance suggestions correctly?

Comment: You can remove the `sqrt` operation and simply compare square distances. And you can do it using only integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

As you return an `rgb16` value in `nearest_1bit_colour` and use it to compare it with other colors and you have to use white and black as returned colors, use 0 and 0xFFFF instead of 0 and 1 (which is black and a very dark gray). Additionally, I think you should compare `c` with 0.5 instead of 1.0:

```
if (c >= 0.5) { 
   r.r = r.g = r.b = 0xFFFF;
} else {
   r.r = r.g = r.b = 0;
}
```

Also, there might be pitfalls with (un)signedness:

```
q.{r,g,b} = old.{r,g,b} - new.{r,g,b};
```

This can get negative, so `q` shouldn't be of type `rgb16` which apparently is `unsigned short`, but of type `short` instead.

Of course, the whole code is for 16-bit input data, for 4- or 8-bit input, you have to change it (or just convert 4-bit and 8-bit data to 16-bit data so you can use the same code).

Comment: After pentrating your English ( ;) ), you make two good points.  Thanks. Not the 'answer', but +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

As purely an integer based solution (my processor doesn't have a FPU), I think this might work.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct rgb16_tag { unsigned short r,g,b; } rgb16;
typedef struct rgb32_tag { unsigned long  r,g,b; } rgb32;

#define LUMINESCENSE_CONSTANT (ULONG_MAX >> (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned short)))

static const rgb32 luminescence_multiplier = {
    LUMINESCENSE_CONSTANT * 0.30f,
    LUMINESCENSE_CONSTANT * 0.59f,
    LUMINESCENSE_CONSTANT * 0.11f
};

int black_or_white( rgb16 p ) {
    unsigned long luminescence;

    assert((  luminescence_multiplier.r
            + luminescence_multiplier.g
            + luminescence_multiplier.b) < LUMINESCENSE_CONSTANT);

    luminescence =   p.r * luminescence_multiplier.r
                   + p.g * luminescence_multiplier.g
                   + p.b * luminescence_multiplier.b;

    return (luminescence > ULONG_MAX/2);  /* 1 == white; */
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good to me, except for the division by three on the multiplier (that's baked into the weights already).

Comment: Yes, the division by three is definitely wrong and it has to be `(ULONG_MAX >> 16)` only. You might consider to write `(unsigned long)(LUMINESCENSE_CONSTANT * 0.30f)` to avoid compiler warnings. One additional minor thing: it's `limits.h` with an s at least for my compiler, but I guess that's just a typo.

Comment: Well, not really 'wrong' just a 1+ bit loss of precision.  Good catch though.

Answer (score 0):

There is some excellent half-toning techniques [HERE](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#kbS_kWlhs3g/src/halftone/main.c&q=Floyd-Steinburg%20lang%3ac)